# terraform azure insufficient blocks

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Here is my terraform plan

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        azure = {
            source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
            version = "=3.5.0"
        }
    }
    backend "s3" {
        encrypt = true
        bucket = "terraform"
        region = "us-east-1"
        key = "aws/tgw_peer/us-east-1/terraform.tfstate"
    }
}



provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}


data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    name = var.vnet_name
}
```

When I execute `terraform plan` I get the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: Insufficient features blocks
│
│   on <empty> line 0:
│   (source code not available)
│
│ At least 1 "features" blocks are required.
╵
```

There is clearly a features block in the azurerm provider block. However, the fact that the error doesn't specify the file name tells me that maybe the problem is somewhere else.
What am I doing wrong?
Terraform version `1.1.6`

Comment: That config is in your root module, and you have no declared modules?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Not sure I get the question. I just have a directory with `tf` files in it that all combine to the terraform plan that I pasted above. And in that directory I terraform init'ed and plan'ed.

Comment: you renamed your provider alias to `azure = {...`. Try to make that `azurerm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the provider in the `required_providers` block is wrong, you have set it to `azure` while it should be `azurerm`. Example of how to configure the provider:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = { # <--- Note that it is azurerm
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  # Configuration options
}
```